# Focus() not working in JavaScript Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm working on a simple form validation with JavaScript and I have a problem when trying to focus() on a field that has been completed incorrectly

//Checking for empty name

```
if (document.forms[0].UserInfo.value == ""){
    document.getElementById("UserInfo").focus();
    errorMessage += "Name cannot be empty \n";
}
```

I've also tried doing it in a different way with no luck

```
document.getElementsByName("UserInfo")[0].focus();
document.forms[0].UserInfo.focus();
```

So essentially, when an alert pops up I want the corresponding field to be highlighted

This is the part of the HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>About You</legend>
    <p id="UserInfo">What is your name?</p>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="UserInfo" size="40">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The id is on the p tag, not the input tag

Comment: too bad you can't change the html, otherwise the `required` attribute would solve the hole thing. Maybe you can get away with it if you do `document.querySelector("input[name='UserInfo']").required = true` :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving your `id="UserInfo"` to the input would make the most sense, but if you can't alter the HTML, try:

```
document.querySelector("input[name='UserInfo']").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UserInfo id is on the P tag - not the input.

So you when you try to target the ID it is choosing the

```
 <p id="UserInfo">What is your name?</p>
```

Switch your ID to the input and it will work.

Comment: thanks, but I cannot change my HTML as this is my homework :)

Answer (score 0):

You've got the id attribute on your p element instead of your input element. If you need that id on the p element for styles or what have you, use a different id on the input element, then document.getElementById() on that id should work.